# Error checking for a fileexist in a script

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm checking for a File.Exists on a package task, but a true precedence constraint never happens because the `Exists()` is always false.

This is part of the code

....

```
if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::varFileExists"].Value = 1;
        }
        else
```

1. The file is in the location, not result.
2. I hard-code the file path, not result.
3. Package run according expected when I run locally, but when I deploy doesn't work.
4. Variables have a right package scope.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your program have sufficient permissions to check that path?

Comment: and can you confirm the values in the variables are correct as well that you are checking, but your code should be correct.  Though I would set a variable to your 1 or 0  then at the end update the variable value

Comment: In order to bring permissions to the right user, I output the variable @[System::UserName] when package is running on production and I added this user to with right to the folder.

Comment: values on variable are ok. package is running with parameters, and they are already setup, just when you deploy to prod doesn't run. nad the issue is file.Exists

Answer (score 0):

When it works locally, but not when deployed, it's usually one of two things:

1. The system user account that the deployed package runs under doesn't have the needed permissions.
2. You are using a local path to a file/folder that exists on your local computer, but doesn't exist on (or can't be reached from) your SSIS server.

Comment: Is pretty confusing for me. first because I'm the same deploying the package, and I have admin right, and second, because the file exist. I also verified with system user is running the package, and added the user with right under the folder. so i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved, and was not related to permissions. The issue was related with using Script Task instead to use Scrip Component.